# Setting field error messages from controller

Tags: grails, gsp

If there's an error message in the fields the error message gets displayed in the GSP as shown below. But i am doing it a bit differently. I want to set the value of the error message from the controller. Code provided below. How can i do this ?

VIEW

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${personInstance}">
                        <ul class="errors" role="alert">
                            <g:eachError bean="${personInstance}" var="error">
                                <li
                                    <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message
                                        error="${error}" /></li>
                            </g:eachError>
                        </ul>
                    </g:hasErrors>
```

CONTROLLER

```
def model = [:]
        model['personInstance'] = personInstance
        if (!personInstance.save(flush: true)) {


            model['mess'] = IF THERE'S AN ERROR IN THE FIELD I WANT TO SET THAT ERROR MESSAGE HERE...
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Do you want the error message for a particular property, do you want to append all of the error messages into 1 String, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really clear what you want to do but for example if you wanted to retrieve all of the error messages and append them to 1 long string separated by `<br/>` tags you could do something like this in a controller...

```
def allErrorsInOneString = personInstance.errors.allErrors.collect {
    g.message(error: it)
}.join('<br/>')
```

Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: The of course if you wanted to put that in the model map that you created in your example you can do that with `model['mess']=allErrorsInOneString`.

Comment: They say that you shouldn't use HTML tags within a controller. Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: Join with a blank space or a comma or whatever you like and it wouldn't be HTML. I showed that as an example and expected that might help with whatever you are really trying to accomplish, which isn't clear. It is obvious that you wouldn't do exactly what is shown in the example because that is better handled in the GSP. There must be some reason that you want to retrieve these messages in a controller. You can use the approach here to retrieve them and do whatever you want to do with them.